# plot_histogram(result.get_counts()) error in qiskit

Tags: qiskit

I tried every way to solve it, but it still does not work .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFTsw.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are no measurements on your circuits, therefore there are no counts. If you add `circuit.measure(qr, cr)` before the execute function then you'll have counts.